# Why does this request get cancelled?

Tags: angular, ionic4, angular-httpclient

I'm setting up a http post request to a local API to store a new wine bottle. The get method works fine but the post just do nothing. Is something missing to my request ? And why do you think the post method call stay silent ?

My research did not help, the only similair issue I could find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54817814/ionic-4-angular-7-httpclient-post-is-not-returning-any-response), but was never answered. Specifying the type like this `this.httpClient.post<WineBatch>` didn't help.

```js
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage'
import { WineBatch } from '../_models/WineBatch'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { ObservableResult } from '../_models/ObservableResult'

@Injectable()
export class WineBatchProvider {
  private storage: Storage
  private storageKey: string
  private apiUrl: string

  constructor(storage: Storage, private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.storage = storage
    this.storageKey = "batches"
    this.apiUrl = 'http://192.168.0.171:8080/api/qns/'
  }

  //#region API

  public refreshWineBatches() {
    this.httpClient.get(this.apiUrl + 'wines').subscribe(result => {
      let observableResult = new ObservableResult(result)
      this.setWineBatches(observableResult.data)
    })
  }

  public addWineBatch(data: any) {
    console.log("Sending data")
    this.httpClient.post(this.apiUrl + 'wines', { data: 'This should cause an error !' }).subscribe(res => {
      console.log("got response !")
    }, error => {
      console.error("error")
    })
    console.log("Data sent !")
  }
  //#endregion
}
```

This code should at least throw an error. Both console.log are called but I get no error, even if I wait for the timeout. On the server side, no error neither or any trace in the log (which logs any API call). It really feels like the `this.httpClient.post()` is simply ignored for some reason.

**Edit**

As Sergey Mell asked, here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45LXj.png) of the network tab (not allowed to have picture in my post yet). The xhr request is instantly cancelled and this bugs as much as it doesn't throw any exception. How the method is called isn't really revelant in this case, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47218216/angular-how-to-know-if-request-has-been-cancelled-in-httpclient) probably is.

> It seems like angular ignores the abort event. Here is the Angular sources: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.0.1/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts
>   The returned Observable does notifiy subscribers if the request is aborted.

But now my question is : *Why does this request get cancelled ?*

Comment: Could you show how do you call this action? And please, attach some screenshot from your Devtools network tab

Comment: While your network tab did show a xhr request being cancelled, I don't think that is always the case. In subsequent lines of the network tab, the API responded with 200 OK. Hence, console.log() was executed, rather than console.error(). Are you sure your API will return NOT ACCEPTED or any other 4xx error when a payload like { data : 'should return error' } is received?

Comment: 200 codes correspond to a simple get, which works perfectly. If I change to route to vines, it returns a 404. But in the post case, the request is never sent. console.log "Sending data" and "Data sent !" are the only ones to show up.

Comment: So nobody is able to find what's wrong ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm seeing the exact same error in a company app and trying to figure out why every single xmlHttp call is immediately cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you might be not sending anything with your written request : try to change your code this way :

```
public addWineBatch(data: any) {
console.log("Sending data")
this.httpClient.post(this.apiUrl + 'wines', data, { observe: 'response' })).subscribe(res => {
  console.log("got response !")
}, error => {
  console.error("error")
})
console.log("Data sent !")
}
```

Comment: The third parameter is used for httpOptions (like headers) but the post method can handle it for you if you don't give any, so trying your suggestion didn't change anything to the result